# Reformatting initialValues in redux-form

Tags: redux, redux-form

I am loading the Redux form with initialValues being passed as props. However, I need to reformat the data so as to fit my form names .. so e.g if the data in initialValues passed as props is {name: 'John', age: '32'}, I want to convert it to {user: {name: 'John', age: '32'}}. How do you achieve it ? Do you write a reducer to accomplish this and if yes then how do you invoke it at the component load ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it when you pass in the prop.

```
const userData = { name: 'John', age: 32 }

...

<MyForm initialValues={{ user: userData }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need some bigger changes, you can also pass a function to initialValues:

```
const getInitialValues = (propValues) => {
  const initialValues = {};

  // your function to format the values here

  return initialValues;
};

@reduxForm(
  {
    form: 'myForm',
    fields: formFields,
  },
  state => ({
    initialValues: getInitialValues(state.userData),
    form: state.form
  })
)
```